# Can SQLAlchemy update the table structure?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am working on my first pylons + SQLAlchemy app (I'm new to both).

As I change my mind on the table structure, I wish there was a similar function to metadata.create_all(), that checks if there are new columns definitions and create them in the database.

Does such a function exist ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not (yet) a SQLAlchemy user, but I've heard good things about [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/). The general term of the problem you have is "schema migration", I'm sure a [google search](http://www.google.ch/search?q=schema+migration+sqlalchemy) containing these terms will help you further.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this term, nor of the existence of such a tool for sqlalchemy-migrate. However, it would be much straightforward for me to just override whatever "create" method in a subclass. Maybe override the Table::create method to alter its structure if it aleready exists in the database.